# pandas comparison raises TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, dataframe

I have the following structure to my dataFrame:

```
Index: 1008 entries, Trial1.0 to Trial3.84
Data columns (total 5 columns):
CHUNK_NAME                    1008  non-null values
LAMBDA                        1008  non-null values
BETA                          1008  non-null values
HIT_RATE                      1008  non-null values
AVERAGE_RECIPROCAL_HITRATE    1008  non-null values

chunks=['300_321','322_343','344_365','366_387','388_408','366_408','344_408','322_408','300_408']
lam_beta=[(lambda1,beta1),(lambda1,beta2),(lambda1,beta3),...(lambda1,beta_n),(lambda2,beta1),(lambda2,beta2)...(lambda2,beta_n),........]

my_df.ix[my_df.CHUNK_NAME==chunks[0]&my_df.LAMBDA==lam_beta[0][0]]
```

I want to get the rows of the DataFrame for a particular chunk lets say `chunks[0]` and particular `lambda` value. So in this case, the output should be all rows in the DataFrame having `CHUNK_NAME='300_321'` and `LAMBDA=lambda1`. There would be n rows one for each `beta` value that would be returned. But instead I get the following error. Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated.

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

`&` has higher precedence than `==`.  Write:

```
my_df.ix[(my_df.CHUNK_NAME==chunks[0])&(my_df.LAMBDA==lam_beta[0][0])]
         ^                           ^ ^                            ^
```

Comment: This precedence has caused me a lot of anguish! Thanks :). Correct me if i'm wrong but I don't think this property is made very apparent in the documentation. It would be nice if someone could add this if not already.

Comment: It is documented here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing  "Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These **must** be grouped by using parentheses."

Comment: The precedence of & is set by Pythons syntax, not pandas.

Answer (score 2):

One way to make sure you don't get into trouble with operator precedence is to use the wrapper methods of comparison operators. For example, use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) method instead of the `==` operator.

Other wrappers are:

- `ne`: `!=`
- `le`: `<=`
- `lt`: `<`
- `ge`: `>=`
- `gt`: `>`

So the expression in OP would be:

```
my_df.loc[my_df.CHUNK_NAME.eq(chunks[0]) & my_df.LAMBDA.eq(lam_beta[0][0])]
```

The wrappers can do more than the comparison operators. You can choose the axis along which to compare. Also, if you're dealing with a MultiIndex object, you can choose the level.

---

**Example:**

For `df`:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  3  5.0
1  2  4  6.0
```

the following line:

```
out = df.loc[df['a']<3 & df['c']==5]
```

results in the following error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and
> scalar of type [bool]
```

However, if we use the equivalent wrappers:

```
out = df.loc[df['a'].lt(3) & df['c'].eq(5)])
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  3  5.0
```