# Pandas loc multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe and I want to delete all rows where column A is equal to blue and also col B is equal to green.

I though the below should work, but its not the case.

Can anyone see the problem

```
df=df.loc[~(df['A']=='blue' & df['B']=='green')]
```

Comment: use `and` instead of `&`?

Comment: `df.loc[~((df['A']=='blue') & (df['B']=='green'))]` , `()` is the problem

Comment: @cripcate why `and` ..??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should separate the two propositions:

```
df1=df.loc[~(df['A']=='blue') & ~(df['B']=='green')]
```

Answer (score 7):

use `eq` instead of `==`:

```
df.loc[~(df['A'].eq('blue') & df['B'].eq('green'))]
```

Comment: this prevents you from [operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333435/pandas-comparison-raises-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with) : Note to OP :)

Comment: Nice comment @anky_91 (-:

Answer (score 4):

#### `query`

Note the `!=` and `or` as consequence of [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
df.query('A != "blue" or B != "green"')
```