# TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, pandas

I ran a command in python pandas as follows:

```
q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TP53']==1) & q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TumorST'].str.contains(':1:'))]]
```

I got following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

the solution i tried using this:
[error link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333435/pandas-comparison-raises-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with).

changed the code accordingly as:

```
q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TumorST'].str.contains(':1:')) & (q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TP53']==1)])]
```

But still I got the same error as `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]`

Comment: your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333435/pandas-comparison-raises-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For filtering by multiple conditions chain them by `&` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TP53']==1) & q1_fisher_r['TumorST'].str.contains(':1:')]
               ^^^^                        ^^^^
           first condition            second condition
```

Problem is this code returned filtered data, so cannot chain by condition:

```
q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TumorST'].str.contains(':1:'))]
```

Similar problem:

```
q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TP53']==1)]
```

**Sample**:

```
q1_fisher_r = pd.DataFrame({'TP53':[1,1,2,1], 'TumorST':['5:1:','9:1:','5:1:','6:1']})
print (q1_fisher_r)
   TP53 TumorST
0     1    5:1:
1     1    9:1:
2     2    5:1:
3     1     6:1

df = q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TP53']==1) & q1_fisher_r['TumorST'].str.contains(':1:')]
print (df)
   TP53 TumorST
0     1    5:1:
1     1    9:1:
```

Comment: the code `q1_fisher[q1_fisher['TumorST'].str.contains(':1:')]` generated 10 lines with 3 lines containing `TP53`.
But when I used your code: `q1_fisher_r[(q1_fisher_r['TP53']==1) & q1_fisher_r['TumorST'].str.contains(':1:')]`.
It does not give the output the 3 lines as expected. It just gave the headers

Comment: @user288925 - Can you add some sample data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @user288925 - Added sample data, working like expected first condition AND second contion

Comment: it works.. I took your data and tried similar way for my data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209530/discussion-between-user288925-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 46):

Had a similar problem with a setup as below, which yielded the same error message. The very simple solution for me was to have **each individual condition between brackets**. Should have known, but want to highlight in case someone else has the same problem.

Incorrect code:

```
conditions = [
    (df['A'] == '15min' & df['B'].dt.minute == 15),  # Note brackets only surrounding both conditions together, not each individual condition
    df['A'] == '30min' & df['B'].dt.minute == 30,  # Note no brackets at all 
]

output = [
    df['Time'] + dt.timedelta(minutes = 45),
    df['Time'] + dt.timedelta(minutes = 30),
]

df['TimeAdjusted'] = np.select(conditions, output, default = np.datetime64('NaT'))
```

Correct code:

```
conditions = [
        (df['A'] == '15min') & (df['B'].dt.minute == 15),  # Note brackets surrounding each condition
        (df['A'] == '30min') & (df['B'].dt.minute == 30),  # Note brackets surrounding each condition
]
    
output = [
        df['Time'] + dt.timedelta(minutes = 45),
        df['Time'] + dt.timedelta(minutes = 30),
]

df['TimeAdjusted'] = np.select(conditions, output, default = np.datetime64('NaT'))
```

Comment: this worked for me, bracketing the individual conditions between the condition & or |

Comment: Thx made me save tons of time

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this? Seems like the interpreter should have no problem identifying `variable == value` as a boolean

Answer (score 5):

simple solution - Have all the conditions inside the bracket-

This throws an error -

```
df[df['Customer Id']==999 & df['month_year']=='10/22']
```

this doesn't -

```
df[(df['Customer Id']==999) & (df['month_year']=='10/22')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach

```
df[(df['Customer Id'].isin([999]) & df['month_year'].isin(['10/22'])]
```