# TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [float64]

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-pandas-filter-with-iqr/
I'm adapting the function to make outliers equal to nan.

```
# Removing the outliers
def removeOutliers(data, col):
    Q3 = np.quantile(data[col], 0.75)
    Q1 = np.quantile(data[col], 0.25)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
      
    print("IQR value for column %s is: %s" % (col, IQR))
    
    lower_range = Q1 - 5 * IQR
    upper_range = Q3 + 5 * IQR
    data.loc[data[col]<= lower_range & data[col]>= upper_range, col]=np.nan


removeOutliers(df, 'Minat')
```

But when i want to use the function in df['Minat'] i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [float64]
```

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: WHERE do you get that error?  Which line, exactly?

Comment: @TimRoberts in data.loc[data[col]<= lower_range & data[col]>= upper_range, col]=np.nan

Comment: Your problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333435/pandas-comparison-raises-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with.  `&` has a higher precedence than `<=` and `>=`, so you must use parentheses to group the comparisons.