# How to check that all non-nan values in dataframe column are > 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe column that may have NaN, which are acceptable, however non-positive values are not acceptable.

I tried to do

```
assert (df[col] > 0).all()
```

But this asserts if there is a nan column.

I also tried

```
assert (df[col] > 0 | df[col] == np.nan).all()
```

But this gives the error

```
E                   TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

What is the appropriate way to check this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas comparison raises TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped \[float64\] array with a scalar of type \[bool\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333435/pandas-comparison-raises-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with). Not direct duplicate, but I think it'll help you solving the issue with your second snippet

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Oh, I actually misread my error. I thought it was saying it can't compare `df[col]` with `np.nan`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych and yes, that does fix my second solution, though I should be using `df[col].isna()`. `df[col] == np.nan` doesn't seem to give the correct output

Comment: With all this said, I feel like there's a better way to do this without having to check for nan?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this using [`df.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html).

Consider this sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, -1, -2, -3],
     'b': [np.nan, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     'c': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]})
```

Then the following can be used to check for negative values:

```
(df['a'] < 0).any(skipna=True) #prints out 'False' 
(df['b'] < 0).any(skipna=True) #prints out 'True'
(df['c'] < 0).any(skipna=True) #prints out 'True'
```

Answer (score 0):

You *do* need to check for NaN-ness.
But `==` equality won't work;
you would need a function like
[np.isnan(x)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html).

Here's what you wanted:

```
assert (df[col].dropna() > 0).all()
```

We [filter out](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html)
the NaN's first, then verify the surviving numbers are all positive.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the nulls with a valid number. In your case positive 1 and then check for any remaining negative numbers.

Basically ensuring that all numbers are null or positive in the column. If there are any negative numbers it will fail.

```
assert df[col].fillna(1).gt(0).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

In writing this...

```py
(df[col] > 0 | df[col] == np.nan)
```

... you've hit two quite nasty Python gotchas.

One is that (np.nan == np.nan) evaluates to False. As another answer has
already indicated, to test for nan you need to use something like
df[col].isna()

The other is that '|' binds more tightly than '>' and '==', so you have
to use nested brackets and write

```py
((df[col] > 0) | df[col].isna())
```